# Evaluate using convolution theorem $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(a^2+t^2)(b^2+t^2)} dt$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

> Evaluate using convolution theorem $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(a^2+t^2)(b^2+t^2)} dt$$

I took $a,b > 0$ and  consider a function $f(x)$ such that:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iwx}}{(a^2+w^2)(b^2+w^2)}$$

Required answer is $\pi f(0)$. Now, consider $\mathfrak{F}\{g(x)\} = \frac{1}{a^2 + w^2}$ and $\mathfrak{F}\{h(x)\} = \frac{1}{b^2+w^2}$, So we have:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathfrak{F}\{g(x)\}\mathfrak{F}\{h(x)\} e^{iwx} dw \\
 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathfrak{F}\{g *h\}  e^{iwx}dw$$

or $f(x) = g * h$.

Now we know $\mathfrak{F}\{e^{-|ax|}\} = \frac{2|a|}{a^2 + w^2}$ so we just need to find $g * -h$ which is:

$$f(0) = \frac{1}{4ab}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|at|} e^{-|bt|} dt = \frac{1}{2ab(a+b)}$$

So $\pi f(0) = \frac{\pi}{2ab(a+b)}$???

---

What if we also did not know fourier inverse of $\frac{1}{a^2+w^2}$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your first question is. To answer your second question, we do know the Fourier inverse though, by the Fourier inversion theorem $$\mathcal{F}(f(x)) = \hat{f}(t) \implies f(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\hat{f}(t))$$

Comment: Sorry, I mean there is a theorem called convolution theorem which is used in this question to prove the integrals value. [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html) . Also, I mean in second question, how can you guess the laplace inverse of $1/(a^2+w^2)$ easily, I looked up the table

Comment: I'm still not understanding your question in regards to the convolution theorem. What exactly is the difficulty you are having in relation to the convolution theorem? And for which transform are you having the difficulty, Laplace of Fourier? For your second question, if you are seeking a Laplace transform and you want to use a LT table, then often you need to modify your integrand so it looks like something in the table. For example, note that $$\frac{1}{a^{2} + \omega^{2}} = \frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{a}{a^{2} + \omega^{2}}$$ Now check your LT table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. We can double-check it with a somewhat easier approach, viz. $$\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{a^2+t^2}-\frac{1}{b^2+t^2}\right)dt=\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2ab(a+b)}$$in the case $a\ne b$ (the case $a=b$ can be handled by continuity using the dominated convergence theorem, but one advantage of Fourier convolution is not having to split the cases like that). But you ask a very good question: what if we don't know the Fourier inverse? I guess one has to either derive it or look it up. If $a>0$, everyone's favourite choice of semicircular contour gives $$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{iwt}dt}{a^2+t^2}=\frac{i}{2a}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{1}{t+ia}-\frac{1}{t-ia}\right)e^{iwt}dt=\frac{i}{2a}\left(0-2\pi i\exp -aw\right)=\frac{\pi}{a}\exp -aw.$$Thus for $a\ne 0$, the integral is $\frac{\pi}{|a|}\exp -|a|w$.

Comment: Thank you! How did you calculate last integral

Comment: @jeea By the residue theorem.